# Invoke method from another form

Tags: c#, methods, invoke

I'm trying to write a program that can display sql databases. I have 2 forms and i want to invoke the displaytable method(which opens a new tabpage on the main form(Form1) for every selected table in the sql database) on Form1.The 2 forms are open at the same time and the second form (From2) is supposed to be closed after the displaytable method has been invoked.

Form1:

```
 
  private void openDatabaseToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//File/Database/Open Database
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                data = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            cn = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + data;
            try
            {
                connection = new OleDbConnection(cn);
                connection.Open();
                Form2 DataSelect = new Form2();
                DataSelect.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception exceptcion)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Such Error! Very Problem: "+exceptcion);
            }
        }

        public  void displaytable() // displays selected table on new tabpage (and dgv)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Form2.selectedtabscount; i++)
            {
                string a = database.ElementAt(i);
                TabPage page = new TabPage(a);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
            }
```

```
    }
```

Fomr2(doesn't work):

 `private void bt_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedtabscount = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;
            Form1.displaytable();
            this.Close();
        }`

I have no idea about how to invoke the displaytable method on Form1.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: If it "doesn't work", "make it work". If you want a good answer here, learn to ask a good question. An error description is part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form1.displaytable();` does not work, because `displaytable` is an instance method. Remember that `Form1` is a class, i.e. a type. You cannot call it on the type `Form1`, instead you must call it on an instance of it.

You can pass an instance of `Form1` to `Form2` through constructor injection. Add a parameter to the constructor of `Form2`

```
private Form1 _form1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _form1 = form1;
}

private void bt_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedtabscount = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;
    _form1.displaytable();
    this.Close();
}
```

In `Form1` you would create an instance of `Form2` like this:

```
Form2 DataSelect = new Form2(this);
```

`Form1` passes its current instance to `Form2` with the `this` keyword.

---

I also noted that you have the same problem with `Form2.selectedtabscount`. It would make much more sense if you added a parameter to the method `displaytable`

```
public void displaytable(int selectedtabscount) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedtabscount; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
    _form1.displaytable(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count);
```

Comment: I'd prefer [events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27677433/594832) instead of coupling the forms tighter than needed.

Comment: Me too; however, it is not easy to explain that to a beginner. I would even implement a kind of messaging system not tied to a form. This could simply be a global (static) event of the kind `SelectionChanged(Type entityType)` in a static class.

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating a new instance of `Form1`. You are not showing it, you need to call the `form1.Show ()` or `form1.ShowDialog()` to show the other form.

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly the same problem as in this question: [I need to access a form control from another class (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658076/i-need-to-access-a-form-control-from-another-class-c/27659346)

You have two options:

- pass a reference from Form1 to Form2 and use it in your `bt_select_Click` method
- or (the better one): define an event in Form2 and subscribe to it from Form1 (use [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659346/594832))