# How to share an event handler between forms

Tags: c#, forms, event-handling

I have a Form1.button1 and Form2.button1.  I would like to have both buttons share the same event handler for when they are clicked.  See comments in the form2.button1_Click event handler.

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // how do I get the form2.button1_Click and the form1.button1_Click 
        // to share the same event handler?
    }
}
```

Any general resources for how to communicate between forms would also be greatly appreciated.  All I currently know to do is set variables and methods as public and pass forms to other forms.

Comment: Can you clarify? I see you have received an answer that is based on a different interpretation of your question than I have, and I want to understand whether I correctly understand the question. Do you want for a single method to handle clicks from buttons in both `Form1` and in `Form2`, or do you want two different handlers to response to clicks from a single button in `Form1`? I assumed the latter because the former is very poor design, but I acknowledge it's possible that's actually what you meant.

Comment: For general communication between forms have a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658076/i-need-to-access-a-form-control-from-another-class-c

Answer (score 1):

If you want to single-source the event handling to just one method, then you'll need to change how the event is subscribed to by one of the buttons.  A quick way to do this is the following:

1. In `Form1`, make `button1_Click()` `public` instead of `private`.
2. In `Form2`, add the following line to the constructor:

   ```
   public Form2(Form1 form1)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.form1 = form1;
       this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.form1.button1_Click);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Given the existing relationship between the two classes, i.e. you are already passing the `Form1` reference to the `Form2` class constructor, you should expose the `Click` event as a new event on `Form1`. That is, encapsulate the actual event with a separate event that wraps the real one.

For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler Button1Click;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello World";

        EventHandler handler = Button1Click;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
        this.form1.Button1Click += button1_Click;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // how do I get the form2.button1_Click and the form1.button1_Click 
        // to share the same event handler?
    }
}
```

That way, the specific implementation in `Form1` can be modified as necessary in the future, without any dependency by any other classes requiring you to fix code elsewhere. All they need to know is that `Form1` has the `Button1Click` event that represents some kind of general clicking action.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to perform same task in both forms. ex : Change textbox from button click of `form1` and also from `form2`

A simpler solution, expose a `public` method in `form1` like follow

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoMyWork();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }

    // Public method to desired work
    public void DoMyWork() (){
       textBox1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And in `form2` use this method like follow (hence you pass `form1` to form2)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
        this.form1.Button1Click += button1_Click;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.DoMyWork(); // perform same work
    }
}
```