# Access form control from another class in another file

Tags: c#, oop, methods, properties

I have 2 .cs files (A, B).

In my A.cs file, it is of public class A. I want to utilize a control (gridview) in public class B, which is in B.designer.cs. Is it possible to do that without inheriting class B in A?

I know I probably need a property and create a new instance of class A in class B. This is what I have so far.

This is in B.cs. I am not sure where/how to do the property.

This is how I define the gridview:
     public DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView

and this is how I write text in it: this.gridView1.OptionsFind.FindNullPrompt = "hello"

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    A gridview = new A();
    A.gridview = "hello";
}
```

Comment: You have 2 classes, and `B` class has a public textbox? The code for class B would help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  If one object needs to reference a property in an existing instance of another object then it needs a reference to that instance.

Comment: You can inject an instance of class A into B's constructor for example to get that reference.  But more importantly, tell us how A and B are related.  Are both of them forms? Is there a main container form? If yes, then A and B could be user controls sitting inside a main form that has instances of both A and B. Then, you could set up events, so that a treeView_node click can set off an event in A to change textbox text value.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493003/how-to-share-an-event-handler-between-forms

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of A in your class B.

You can get it like this:

```
public class B
{
    private A theA;
    public B(A theA)
    {
        this.theA = theA;
    }

    private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        theA.textbox = "hello";
    }
}
```

Now, when you create your instance of class B, you write it like this.

```
B b = new b(new A());
```

Comment: How do I ensure that I'm specifying at the textbox I want to write "Hello" in?

Comment: @Annie123 When you add the textbox to class A, it gets a name. When you say theA.textbox in class B, make sure ".textbox" is the name of the textbox in class A. The name of the textbox you want ot write to.

Comment: so theA is just a random variable, but ."textbox" is the name of the textbox

Comment: The textbox is actually defined like this:      public DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridViewTest and this is how I write text in it: this.gridView1.OptionsFind.FindNullPrompt = "hello"

Comment: @Annie123 Well, it's not random, its your instance of your class A. but yeah, if your Textbox in class a is called textbox, you can say theA.textbox. If it is called txtHello, then you'd say: theA.txtHello. This works the same as it would with any other kind of variable.

Comment: @Annie123 So you don't access it via class A? I think it would help if you edit your question to include more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    A gridview = new A();
    A.gridview = "hello";
}
```

In this part of your code,

First, you are creating a new instance of A called "gridview", but then use

> A.gridview = "hello"

to try to access the gridview which should actually be

> gridview.gridview = "hello";

Second, by creating a new instance of A and change the value of its field "gridview"(which I think it may be a textbox according to your code), it will not have any effect to the interface as this is not the A you want to reference.

Instead, it should probably be:
In class B, something like,

```
Public void UpdateAGridview(A yourA)
{
    yourA.gridview = "hello";
    //side note: setting a string value to a gridview, is this correct?
}
```

Here you get a reference to the A you want to interact with, so the "gridview" in the A will be the one you want to update.