# How to pass the data of supplied Username/Password back to MDI parent form(toolstrip) in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm having a hard time on passing a value from database to Stripmenu. Here's my Code.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection cmdConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cmdConn;
        try
        {

            if (cmdConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmdConn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select username, hashpassword from matt.Users where UserName=@UserName AND HashPassword=@HashPassword;";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@UserName", Value = txtUsername.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@HashPassword", Value = txtPassword.Text });
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                BindingSource rcdBS = new BindingSource();
                DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dtTable);

                if (dtTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
 //this is what i want to pass to the MDI form inside the toolstrip (tbTechsupp.Text)
  cmd.CommandText = "select FullName from matt.Users where Username  ='" + txtUsername.Text + "'"; 


                  stripMenuSetting.showMenuStriptool("TransctToolStripMenu", "statsToolStripMenu");
                  this.Close();


                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/Password!");
                }
                }
            cmdConn.Close();
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Right now, my code works like, buttons from menu strip will be enabled if I have the correct credentials. how to add an sql statement that will pass its value to the toolstrip of another form.

here's my main form after I supplied the username and password.. That is where I want to pass my sql statement that looks like "select FullName from matt.Users where username = 'txt.UserName.text' "

hope someone can help me. TIA

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658076/i-need-to-access-a-form-control-from-another-class-c

Answer (score -1):

I hope i understand your question the right way ^^

if you want to change a property of a control of a Form from another Class you could do one of the following:

```
//################################## 1.
//write a property 
public string myProp 
{
     get{ return controlXY.TextProp; }
     set{ controlXY.TextProp = value; }
}

//################################## 2.
//write an delegate
public delegate void GetWhatEver(type param);
//call the delegate in an event
private void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, args e)
{
    if(GetWhatEver != null)
    {
         GetWhatEver(e.data);
    }
}
//pass this delegate to the form
OtherClass.GetWhatEver = SetWhatEver;
```

Be careful if you are coming from another thread, you might need to invoke the other one ;)