# how to select an item in a combobox in another form?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have form1 and form2. in form1, i have a combobox that bind to sql.
i want in form2 with press a button, show form1 and select an item in combobox.

![for load my form1. cbGroup is name of combox and frmAdd is name of form1][1]

```
    private void frmAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db=new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var q=from c in db.Groups
              select c.GroupName;
        cbGroup.DataSource = q;
    }
```

![this codes inside a button on form2][2]

```
        frmAdd ff = new frmAdd();
        ff.cbGroup.SelectedIndex = f.cbGroup.Items.IndexOf("Summer");
        ff.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658076/i-need-to-access-a-form-control-from-another-class-c

Comment: thats's bad. i need help for this question.

Comment: The base problem is the same as yours. You can apply the solution provided there to your case.

Comment: i can not do it. please help me

Comment: @RasulEbrahimzadeh: you want to open form1 from from 2 with button click ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am i right you want to open `frmAdd` and passing some value which combobox item and you want to selected item when `frmAdd` open

```
private string _yourcomboboxitem=string.Empty; // Here i make a private field to store your data 
public string Yourcomboboxitem // make public property 
{
    get{return _comboboxitem;}
    set{ comboboxitem = value;}
}
private void frmAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        DataClasses1DataContext db=new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var q=from c in db.Groups
              select c.GroupName;
        cbGroup.DataSource = q;
       cbGroup.SelectedItem = this.Yourcomboboxitem; // when form load your comboxbox will set item which you assign value to your property
 }
```

Button click event of `form2`

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        frmAdd ff = new frmAdd();
        ff.Yourcomboboxitem = "Summer";// here i am Assigning value to property which i created in frmAdd 
        ff.ShowDialog();
 }
```

**Updated:**

There are many approaches by which you can pass data between forms

1. The Constructor Approach
2. The Object Approach
3. The Delegates Approach
4. The Properties Approach
5. The Method Approach

**Reference:**

**[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)**

**[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to doing so
1-Using a ViewModel file
2-the easier way is to add a method to the form that host the combo box as below:

```
public void ShowWithCustomComboBoxItem(int itemNumber)
{
cbGroup.SelectedIndex=itemNumber;
this.ShowDialog();
}
```