# Calling method in other class (Windows Form) in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have two forms "Form1" and "Form2"
now I want to call the method "change_lbl()" that exist in "Form1" from "Form2" but when I call the method in "Form2" it is not implemented and is unable to execute

Codes Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void change_lbl()
    {
        lbl_form1.Text = "Its Done !";
    }

    private void btn_gofrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Codes Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.change_lbl();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Each instance that is `new`-ed up is a separate identity. You have form 2 creating a form 1 which can create **another** form 2. Is this just a quick example or are you actually creating multiple forms from each form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to access a form control from another class (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658076/i-need-to-access-a-form-control-from-another-class-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code is correct and method invokes correctly! you are creating and using a new instance of `Form1` without showing it, but it looks you are expecting to see changes in default instance of `Form` that is using by Application and currently is open. 
to have the open instance of `Form1` class:

```
Form1 myForm1=(Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
```

Comment: thank you Mehrdad , 
why  when i click in upvote . 0 for a moment converte to 1, but it turned out to be a 0 again

Comment: @W01FSbane no problem, I'll happy if the problem resolves.

Comment: You're welcom! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at this project. This might solve your problem. Basically when you call Form2 and click a button( I mean a Form2 button) then Form1 must 'capture' the event i.e an event like Form2buttonClicked. Take a look at this article to know more.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms

This might be a little irrelevant but this might help you as well
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

Comment: when i click in upvote . 0 for a moment  converte to 1, but it turned out to be a 0 again :(

Comment: I'm new in here. The voting thing is really demoralizing :( . Kindly try that again if you are benefitted :v LOL . And I'm happy that it solved your problem W01FSbane :)

Comment: thank you K.G aka , i tried again to upvote you , but it don't work again :(

Comment: It happened with me too. I saw a pop out in the process and it said, my votes will be visible when I'll have a reputation of 15. Maybe this is also valid for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `EventHander` in `Form2` and subscribe to that event in `Form1`. Work's fine

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ButtonClicked != null);
           ButtonClicked(sender, new EventArgs());
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now in `Form1` subscribe to the event and call `change_lbl()`

```
private void btn_gofrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.ButtonClicked += (se,ev) => change_lbl();
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: thank you Hari Prasad .this help me , but
when i click in upvote . 0 for a moment converte to 1, but it turned out to be a 0 again :(  . what do i do now

Comment: I guess, you don't have enough reputations to up vote :-). You could only mark as answer.